# Referenced ICC Output Profile for PDF/X-4p using iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, itext, pdf-generation

We are using iTextSharp 5.5.0, and looking for code to set output intent keeping ICC output profile as externally referenced for use and to have PDF/X-4p standard.

Please suggest me the code to input the icc profile and set the icc profile as externally referenced as in the Screenshot.

[image: Referenced ICC Profile]

Comment: Have you looked at the [official documentation](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/zugferd/zugferd-tutorial-examples-chapter-2#3-c2e3_pdfa3b.java) on how to add the output intent?

Comment: @JonReilly The example program you are referencing creates a PDF/A file that has the ICC profile for the output intent embedded in the PDF file. The question is about PDF/X-4p where an external ICC profile is referenced from the PDF file as output intent.

Comment: @JonReilly, Yes. We have the code for Set Output Intent, It is working fine. But we are looking for the code suggestion for ICC profile to be externally referenced.

Comment: Ah, I see. In general iText doesn't have helper classes or function for print-specific implementations of PDFs (Disclaimer: I work for iText). It should still be possible since we offer the ability to edit the low-level content, but I can't find the PDF/X specification to know exactly what should go in the output intent. You should be able to use [RUPS](https://github.com/itext/rups) to view the contents of your PDF and replicate it via the library.